# Postgresql select for thermal printer

Tags: postgresql, hex, decimal, thermal-printer, pos

I'm creating a select for a POS thermal printer and I need to send chr (0) to the printer. The problem is that Postgresql does not allow chr (0). Is there another way to send decimal 0 to the printer via string?
By default, select would look like this:

```
select string(chr(29)||chr(33)||chr(0))
```

The printer can also accept hex 00, but using

```
select string ((chr (29) || chr (33) || to_hex(00))
```

does not work on the printer.

Printer model: RONGTA PP220

Data send via Low BLE profile in Swift

```
    func printText(_ str:String) {
        let cfenc = CFStringEncodings.dosLatin2
        let enc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(cfenc.rawValue))
     
        let data = str.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: enc), allowLossyConversion: false)
        if data != nil{
            sendCommand(data!)
        }
    }

    func sendCommand(_ data:Data) {
        send(value: data)
    }

    private func send(value:Data) {
      
        if (currentPeripheral != nil) || (writeCharacteristic != nil) {   currentPeripheral!.writeValue(value, for: writeCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
        }
    
    }
```

Yes, I can send (29,33,0) in Swift, but my intention is to created the whole receipt in Postgresql.

Comment: Try `bytea` instead of character type: `select '\x1d2100'::bytea;`

Comment: It only prints the text. Another idea?

Comment: I have no any other ideas because I don't know anything about your printer and I don't know anything about how you send data to it. If you need to control your device at low level then usually you should to send byte sequences to its port and `bytea` type is most suitable for that. Clarify your question with more technical details if you want to get more detailed answer.